Can’t add List selection binding from an array of protocol conforming types
I have a List loading from an array of protocol conforming types. When I add a selection binding to the List the compiler won’t longer compile the code.

The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

When I try using a Set instead of an Array I get an error.

Type 'any IRow' cannot conform to 'Hashable'

protocol IRow: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID { get }
    var rowType: String { get }
}

struct TextItemRow: IRow {
    let id = UUID()
    let rowType = "text"
    
    var text: String = ""
}

struct HeadlineItemRow: IRow {
    let id = UUID()
    let rowType = "headline"
    
    var text: String = ""
}

struct Item {
    let id = UUID()
    var rows: [any IRow] = [HeadlineItemRow(text: "H_mock"), TextItemRow(text: "T_mock")]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let item = Item()
    @State private var selection: [any IRow] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(item.rows, id: \.id) { row in
                    if let r = row as? HeadlineItemRow {
                        Text("\(r.id.uuidString) : \(r.text)")
                            .tag(row)
                    } else if let r = row as? TextItemRow {
                        Text("\(r.id.uuidString) : \(r.text)")
                            .tag(row)
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("")
        }
        .frame(width: 250)
    }
}


Inheritance is better for something like this that way you can have a concrete “super”, SwiftUI does not like existentials since they don’t conform to the protocols they require.

Thanks. I implemented the solution using classes but struggle then with the ForEach(item.rows… part.

That wouldn’t change

Could figure it out. Thanks again.
